# How to create a dictionary with tuple keys in a numba njit fuction

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, numba, jit

Im pretty inexperienced with numba (and posting questions) so hopefully this isn't a miss-specified question.

I am trying to create a jitted function that involves a dictionary. I want the dictionary to have tuples as keys, and floats as values. Below is some code from the numba help found [on the numba docs](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.43.0/reference/pysupported.html), that I've used to help demonstrate my question.

I understand numba wants variables types to be specified. The problem I think is that I am not specifying the right numba type as the dictionary key inside the function. I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57514336/how-should-i-use-an-array-or-tuple-as-key-and-values-for-a-numba-typed-diction)  but still cant figure out what to do.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
from numba import types
from numba.typed import Dict

# Make array type.  Type-expression is not supported in jit functions.
float_array = types.float64[:]

@njit
def foo():
    list_out=[]
    # Make dictionary
    d = Dict.empty(
        key_type=types.Tuple, #<= I suppose im not putting the right 'type' here
        value_type=float_array,
    )
    # an example of how I would like to fill the dictionary
    d[(1,1)] = np.arange(3).astype(np.float64)
    d[(2,2)] = np.arange(3, 6).astype(np.float64)
    list_out.append(d[(2,2)])
    return list_out

list_out = foo()
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`types.Tuple` is an **incomplete type** and so not a valid one. You need to specify the type of the items in the tuple. In this case, you can use **`types.UniTuple(types.int32, 2)`** as a complete key type (a tuple containing two 32-bit integers). Here is the resulting code:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
from numba import types
from numba.typed import Dict

# Make key type with two 32-bit integer items.
key_type = types.UniTuple(types.int32, 2)

# Make array type.  Type-expression is not supported in jit functions.
float_array = types.float64[:]

@njit
def foo():
    list_out=[]
    # Make dictionary
    d = Dict.empty(
        key_type=key_type, 
        value_type=float_array,
    )
    # an example of how I would like to fill the dictionary
    d[(1,1)] = np.arange(3).astype(np.float64)
    d[(2,2)] = np.arange(3, 6).astype(np.float64)
    list_out.append(d[(2,2)])
    return list_out

list_out = foo()
```

By the way, be aware that `arange` accept a `dtype` in parameter so you can use `np.arange(3, dtype=np.float64)` directly which is more efficient when using `astype`.